# Google collab showing error: tuple object is not callable

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

I'm trying to fine tune open ai's whisper model using google colab and in the last step I'm getting this error.

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

**input**
trainer.train()
I would much appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
here is the tutorial that I'm following for additional reference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O60EnXcbi6g